# No gazebo-ros package after update?

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-hydro, update

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After the recent 2.0.0 Gazebo update, I can no longer run gazebo_ros. It has been deinstalled during the update. When trying to install gazebo-ros-pkgs, I get the following output:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-hydro-gazebo-ros-control : Depends: ros-hydro-gazebo-ros but it is not going to be installed
 ros-hydro-gazebo-ros-pkgs : Depends: ros-hydro-gazebo-plugins but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-hydro-gazebo-ros but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When trying to install the mentioned ros-hydro-gazebo-ros, this is the output:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-hydro-gazebo-ros : Depends: gazebo but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: ros-hydro-gazebo-plugins but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Yet, gazebo is installed and can be run.

Is there something broken in the repository?

*EDIT:*
This issue: https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues/126 does indeed state a problem in the repository, but it is not released yet. I'm looking for people who have the same problem or have found a workaround.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/89501/no-gazebo-ros-package-after-update?/) by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) on ROS Answers with karma: 386 on 2013-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This problem was resolved. This e-mail discusses the solution: http://gazebosim.org/pipermail/gazebo-list/2013-October/000039.html.

---

Originally posted by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) with karma: 386 on 2013-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gaussian](https://answers.ros.org/users/21014/gaussian/) on 2015-01-23**:
this page is broken.. please provide a solution